# ZedGraph - How to save the chart data that is being generated by ZedGraph?

Tags: c#, xls, zedgraph

ZedGraph - How to save the chart data that is being generated by ZedGraph?

ZedGraph Using Line Chart, C # and Serial Port:
How to save the chart data that is being generated by ZedGraph in XLS format file?
ocaccy

Comment: I only can tell you, how to save in csv. Would that do?

Comment: I'm saving csv before entering the graphics, but I need to save the data that are within the ZedGraph. In ZedGraph is not stored in array?
Thanks,
ocaccy

Comment: So your data for ZedGraph comes from csv? Then I don't understand, you already have the data in csv.

Comment: I am very new to programming with C # and I'm picking up a little.
Taking this opportunity.
How do I split a large code in code smaller?
How to create classes that have harmony with each other and pass information to each other?
I have 6 devices connected to a converter RS485/USB.

Comment: When sending the command I activate the six main devices, and receive a message.
I'm building a routine that automatically sends commands ID01, ID02, ID03, ID04, ID05 and ID06.
By sending each command takes a string IDXX  01,22008,21930,00000, n / a, n / an / a!
Then share with substring () and throw in a file as csv.
I need to take that array as if it were a spreadsheet with 310 rows by 120 columns.
Once you know which is the highest value, the Value and Average a set of cells within the array.
Forgive me and very grateful for the help,
ocaccy